# How to use a .js file?

Tags: javascript

I'm sorry for this very newbish question, I'm not much given into web development. I've got this cool JavaScript in a .js file that we want to use on a small web site. (It's a script to run Cooliris on it).

How do use the .js file or attach it to my HTML code?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just include this line anywhere in your HTML page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourfile.js"></script>
```

Don't forget the closing tag as IE won't recongize it without a separate closing tag.

Comment: In HTML the closing tag is required anyway.

(In XHTML you can use empty element syntax if you use an XML content-type, but Appendix C "forbids" it for XHTML masquerading as HTML)

Comment: What I meant that even in XHTML, IE won't understand <script type="text/javascript" src="yourfile.js" />

Comment: As I said - Appendix C "forbids" that (and the page won't work at all in IE if you use an XML content-type).

Answer (score 7):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js"></script>
```

Usually inserted in the <head> tag. After that, it depends wether or not your script need additional initialization or customisation to work.

Comment: You are missing the (required) type attribute.

Comment: type="text/javascript"

very important.

Comment: This required type is useless. First of all JS is the only scripting language accros all the browser (VBS is IE only and nearly dead). Then you sould rely on the MIME type sent by the server and not by the one written in the tag.

Comment: If nothing else, specifying the type stops validators from outputting an error. Having lots of errors that you don't care about makes it harder to find errors you DO care about.

Comment: Insert before </body> improves performance, and also allows DOM queries when script loads.

Comment: @eyelidlessness: You're right, except if the JS script has to do some DOM computation before that all the rest of the page is loaded. It was often the case with "old way" scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Do a view source on this page.

Answer (score 0):

use this script with in head tag.and your JS file path with name of ur file

```
<html>
  <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="url+yourfilename.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```